# objects.location request in a for loop won't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, blender, bpy

I've started to use Python in blender.
I'm trying to get armatures on individual objects for an animation and I'm trying to run the following script:

```
for count in range(1, value, 1):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[count]
    loc = bpy.data.objects[count].location
    bpy.ops.object.armature_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(loc[0], loc[1], 0.1), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

The result gives all armatures on the first object. It seems that the variable `loc` doesn't update.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: did you try `print(loc)` to see what you get in variable? You can use `print()` also to check other varaibles.

Comment: I did. It looks like the `count` updates, however `loc` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!

My old script would add a new object "Armature.001" to `bpy.data.objects` which appears before "Cube.001" in the objects list.

So the forloop would move forward but so would all the objects thus having no effect.